# How to find a basis for this and the Dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra

*Question:*
$$W=\{(x,y,z,w)∈\mathbb{R}^4 \ : \ x+3y+4z+4w=0, \ y−1z−2w=0\}$$

is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$. Find a basis for W. State the dimension of W.

---

*Answer:*

What I did was I put this into reduce row echelon form like a null space.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 4 & 4 & |0\\ 0 & 1 & -1 & -2 & |0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 7 & 10 & |0\\ 0 & 1 & -1 & -2 & |0 \end{bmatrix}$$

**I dont know what to do next. What should I do next?**

Answer (score 1):

Now you need to read the equations of the row echelon form. Since the pivots are in the $1$ and $2$ positions, these look like:

$$x_1 = -7x_3 - 10x_4 \\
x_2 = x_3+2x_4.$$

This tells you what $x_1,x_2$ are provided you have values of $x_3,x_4$, which are not specified. Hence these are free parameters. As a result, you can assemble a basis by choosing two pairs of values of $x_3,x_4$, such that the resulting vectors are linearly independent. An easy way to do this which will always work is to take $x_3=1,x_4=0$ and then $x_3=0,x_4=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not use a matrix for this.  Just note that if $x+ 3y+ 4z+ 4w= 0$ and $y- z- 2w= 0$ then, from the second equation, $y= z+ 2w$ and then the first equation becomes $x= -3y- 4z- 4w= -3(z+ 2w)- 4z- 4w= -7z- 10w$.  So we can write any vector as $(x, y, z, w)= (-7z- 10w, z+ 2w, z, w)= (-7z, z, z, 0)+ (-10w, 2w, 0, w)=$ $z(-7, 1, 1, 0)+ w(-10, 2, 0, 1)$.